# SQL line break not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have below code:-

```
DECLARE @NewLineChar AS CHAR(23) = CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
select 'abc'+@NewLineChar+'a'
```

I expect the result to be:-

```
abc
a
```

In single row

But its showing me as below:-

[image]

What changes should I make to above code?

**EDIT1**

[image]

**EDIT2**

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `PRINT` and not `SELECT` to display the result.

```
DECLARE @NewLineChar AS VARCHAR(23) = CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
PRINT 'abc'+@NewLineChar+'a'
```

(Don't forget to move to the *Messages* tab to view the result)

The SSMS grid display does not display line breaks or newline characters.

Comment: But I want to display it in row result

Comment: @CSharper You can't. It's not something that you can control or something that even matters within SSMS. Your output is correct (if you check the messages tab), but not when using the grid display. If you return this result to an application then that will (should) show up correctly.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu - RE: can't control there is one relevant option https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbJAK.png (still won't display it but will preserve on copy and paste)

Comment: BTW you also only need declare '@newlinechar' as char(2)!  not (23) you are not adding 10 + 13.  Just providing two chars.  It also works with char(13) by itself - in this case '@newlinechar' becomes char(1).  If you have char(23) you get 21 white spaces in result

Comment: @JonathanWillcock Good spotting! I just copy pasted the OP's original code, but that's something good to add.

Comment: same..cant find this option in SSMS 2016

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu - yes. https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFU13.gif (copying the SSMS result and pasting to the query window)

Answer (score 2):

It will work. But you have to see the result in `Result to text` output

```
select 'abc'+ CHAR(13) +'a'
```

When using the results to grid option, SSMS use the standard Windows grid control to display the results. This grid control treats each cell value as a plain text and hence the new line characters are ignored.

However if you use the results to text option or the results to file the new line characters are retained.

Refer : https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/381955/sql-server-management-studio-should-show-new-lines-in-records

Enable `Result to text` by pressing `ctrl + t` then run
[image: Text output]

Comment: But its same as printing..cant I use this in result grid of query itself?

Comment: @CSharper No you can't grid view skips newline characters

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @NewLineChar AS VARCHAR(2)

SET @NewLineChar = CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)

PRINT 'abc'+@NewLineChar+'a'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use below query for new line :

```
  DECLARE @strPrint VARCHAR(100);
  SET @strPrint = 'abc';
  SET @strPrint = @strPrint + CHAR(13);
  SET @strPrint = @strPrint + 'a';
  SELECT  @strPrint;

  Edit : 

  Use PRINT for see new line   

  PRINT @strPrint;
```

Answer (score 1):

U have to concat string with `CHAR(13)` This should work:

```
DECLARE @NewLineChar NVARCHAR(200);
SET @NewLineChar = 'abc' + CHAR(13) + 'a';
PRINT @NewLineChar;
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
abc
a
```

Answer (score 1):

To test your output, if using SSMS make sure the option Retain CR/LF on copy or save is checked, else all pasted results will loose the line feed. You find this at settings, query results, sql server, results to grid.

Comment: Note that you have to create a new query tab for the change to take effect.